# Moving to Entity Framework v4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, efv4

I know that **EFv4** is still in **Beta2**, but I would like to hear your opinions:

1. When are you considering to make the move from EFv1 to EFv4? Are you waiting for the final version of .NET Framework 4.0?
2. Will you move (or planning to move) your current project's Data Acess from EFv1 to EFv4? When will you start?
3. Would you use current EFv4 Beta2 in production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you update your project from 3.5 to 4.0, you end up using the new version of the assembly. The real changes come when you start using the new features, like the Self-Tracking Entities or Complex Types. That being said, we have already moved to beta 2, but the full release should happen before we go to production.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 4 Beta 2 is released with a [go-live license](http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/archive/2009/10/19/going-live-with-visual-studio-2010-beta-2.aspx) so Microsoft will support EFv4 in production.